# bootstrap how to inherit font-size-small variable?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, bootswatch

I have a PHP application that uses Twitter Bootstrap and allows the user to select the preferred Bootswatch theme. In the application, there is a PHP class to build a datagrid (table thead tbody tfoot), however within the `<td>` element was inserted into the `<small>`, then removed the `<small>` and decide to use CSS.

```
td { font-size:0.85em; vertical-align: middle !important; }
```

However, several Bootswatch themes using a less variable @font-size-small, and I would like my datagrid reuse this variable, in other words, when the user to choose a Bootswatch theme, the datagrid font size would be adjusted based on the theme and not explicitly defined by `font-size:0.85em;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have some ways to do this, one of them is specify a class in the body or in the container to change the style which theme is selected.

Like this:

```
body.theme1 {
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

body.theme2 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

or in LESS/SASS:

```
body.theme1 {
  font-size: @font-size-small;
}

body.theme2 {
  font-size: @font-size-small-theme2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I believe you are doing something wrong when using LESS, from what I understood reading 'http://lesscss.org/', I first link my .less stylesheets with the rel attribute set to "stylesheet/less": `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />` and add `<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, but unfortunately I see no change. My styles.less: `body { font-size: @font-size-small; }`

Comment: @MagnoAlberto For your code works, you need to include the js before your .less `<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`